# Converting from typical input "dd/mm/aaaa" to valid Symfony values

Tags: php, forms, doctrine, validation, symfony-1.4

I've a table where I set a field as TIMESTAMP, then I generate a module using tasks `doctrine:generate-admin`. By default Symfony creates a `_form.php` template where TIMESTAMP fields come separately as for example:

```
alumnos_fecha_ingreso_day
alumnos_fecha_ingreso_month
alumnos_fecha_ingreso_year
alumnos_fecha_ingreso_hour
alumnos_fecha_ingreso_minute
```

So in my template I've a field where values are entered as "dd/mm/yyyy" (is the default format) and I don't want to use Symfony way (it's ugly for end users). My question is how I deal with this value in order to get the right value and Symfony pass form validation? Is there any way to hide Hour and Minutes fields? Or is complety necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want day/month/year, you have to define the option `with_time` to false inside your form class.

> `with_time`: Whether to include time (true by default)

And in your form:

```
$this->widgetSchema['my_date'] = new sfWidgetFormDateTime(array(
  // I don't remember if you need to re-define the format
  'date'      => array('format' => '%day%/%month%/%year%'),
  'with_time' => false
));
```

Comment: ok, see this is my HTML markup for `fecha_ingreso` field: `<input id="alumnos_fecha_ingreso" name="alumnos[fecha_ingreso]" class="span2" type="text" placeholder="dd-mm-aaaa" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">` then using jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap I do this `$('#alumnos_fecha_ingreso').datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
            });` my question is, if I send the form I'll not have any problems with that date format even doing the changes in my AlumnosForm.class.php?

Comment: You then should change the format to `%day%-%month%-%year%`. But I don't really know how hour & minute will be handle. Maybe 00:00.

Comment: thanks I think it will be handle as you said 00:00 I'll give a try and let you know how it goes and then accept your question